# How to add shortname for clusterrolebinding in kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to add a shortname for clusterrolebinding in kubectl and not via bash alias?

Answer (score 2):

No there is no shortname for `clusterrolebinding` at this moment. You can see this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/86138).

The reason not having shortname for `clusterrolebinding` as the issue told is: **We've typically only added short names for commonly used CLI resources.**

Comment: His question is not that if it is existed, but how to add a new shortname for a kubernetes resource.

Comment: my bad! then either kubectl need to add such shortname or you can write your own kubectl type tool by client-go, cause under the hood kubectl use client-go to contact with kubernetes api server. That means, basically you cannot add such shortname in kubectl until the respected authority do that